# Data passing of photo taken in App

Tags: ios, image, camera

I used the code

```
  -(IBAction)TakePhoto {
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
picker.delegate = self;
[picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"CropImage" sender:sender];
}


- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

//obtaining saving path
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"latest_photo.png"];

//extracting image from the picker and saving it
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.image"]){
    UIImage *editedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    NSData *webData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(editedImage);
    [webData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
}
}
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel  :(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}

 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"CropImage"])
{
    CropImageViewController *cropImageViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    cropImageViewController.theImage = yourImage;
    // Similar to [segue.destinationViewController setTheImage:yourImage];
    }
 }
```

I have a problem here using the storyboard. I have multiple view controllers in the storyboard.  I have the camera button (which the user can take the photo in app) on the first view controller. However I want to pass the data of the photo that the user took in the first view controller to another view controller automatically so that the user can crop it and then save it into a "directory or something"(did not decide yet).

update
I am having now four errors currently saying 
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=15q6y3b&s=5
Click the image it will be bigger

Comment: So what is the problem? You don't know how to pass the data or you don't know how to call the next view?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to pass the data(photo)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't have to pass the photo directly to the next view since you had already saved it. You can simply read back the image from the same file in the target view controller. (This method is better if the view controllers are not close to one another.)

```
+ (UIImage *)readImageFromFile:(NSString *)name
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"latest_photo.png"];

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
    return [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}
```

UPDATED: You can also pass the photo using property though.

In your target view controller (I will name it CropImageViewController), in .h,

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *theImage;
```

In the "getPhoto" view controller, on top of the page,

```
#import "CropImageViewController.h"
```

In imagePickerController,

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
    ...
    // This line should be
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"CropImage" sender:self];
}
```

In prepareForSegue method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"CropImage"])
    {
        CropImageViewController *cropImageViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        cropImageViewController.theImage = yourImage;
        // Similar to [segue.destinationViewController setTheImage:yourImage];
    }
}
```

Make sure you set a name, e.g. "CropImage", for the segue identifier in storyboard.

Comment: I want to do the second one using the property. I want the user to take a photo and that photo goes to another view controller where the user can crop and then SAVE. So if I use the first one it saves automatically before sending to the crop view controller  rite?

Comment: The first solution is based on what you had already done, I simply expanded on that approach. Since you prefer the second method, have you solved the problem?

Comment: I don't get the second code [segue.destinationViewController setTheImage:yourImage]; I wrote @property code in the cropview controller.  Where do I write the second code?

Comment: Write the second code in the view controller where you obtain the photo. Also, show the code in the prepareForSegue method if you have one.

Comment: I'm getting confused having three errors, I edited my code in the question can you look at it?

Comment: Sorry asking too many questions at once..can you look at the picture?

Comment: You need to change "CropImageViewController" to the name of your controller, similarly, "yourImage" should be the name of a variable you used to store the image from the picker (editedImage). Don't just copy my code word for word.