# photo passing dosen't work

Tags: ios, image, photo

I want to pass the data of the photo that the user took in the first view controller to another view controller automatically so that the user can crop it and then save it into a "directory or something"(did not decide yet).
This is my code for the . h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
UIImagePickerController *picker;
UIImagePickerController *picker2;
UIImage *image;
IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview;

}

- (IBAction)TakePhoto;
```

However I have errors like this in the picture and I don't know why this is happening.
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=29nyxli&s=5

I have also put

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *theImage;
```

for the .h file in the second view controller(CropViewController) . I did not add anything in the .m file..

Comment: Curious - why do you have two ivars for a `UIImagePickerController`?

Comment: Oh my... You actually duplicate your own question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713158/data-passing-of-photo-taken-in-app/17713922#17713922 when answer was already provided. Seems like you want exact answers to be provided instead of figuring out why.

Comment: It didnt work still with having too many errors...

Comment: @user2590480 It didn't work not because of error in that answer but your lack of basic programming knowledge. You simply left that thread hanging instead of clarifying things. My advise for you is to pick up the basic first. Anyway, I hands off. Please close the other thread.

Answer (score 0):

Two **separate** ideas.

1. Import your CropViewController in your header file.

2. Put this in your header file:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
UIImagePickerController *picker;
UIImagePickerController *picker2;
UIImage *image;
IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview;
CropViewController *cropVC //or whatever you decided to call this
}
```

Comment: I still get the use of undeclared identifier "sender" in the    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"CropImage" sender:sender];

Comment: Which method did you use?

Comment: Okay. What you want to do is change `sender:sender` to `sender: self`. Then, you want to make sure the segue was made from the VIEW CONTROLLER to another view controller. A general mistake is linking a button to a view controller (even if you want to use the button). Does this make sense?

Comment: Awesome! Glad to be of help. I remember when I had to deal with the segue issue. It took me while to figure out, so I'm glad you've gotten through.

Comment: Wait i still have an error saying     @autoreleasepool    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])); SIGABRT I don't have errors though..

Comment: Okay. Few things you can do. Look in the debugger to see what happened. Make sure breakpoints are off.

Comment: Also, the CropImage segue should me made like this: in storyboard, make the segue in the document outline (view controller to another view controller). It is important that you connect the controllers, and not a button. Name this segue CropImage. Let me know the results.